# Preview FFMPEG subtitles before encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to burn in subtitles using a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subs.srt:force_style='Fontsize=24,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

I'd like to create a sort of preview of what the the encoded file with subtitles will look like in the browser before the user clicks "Encode video".  I've been creating a DIV with each bit of text from the .srt file and overlaying it on top of a VIDEO tag.  I've then been fiddling with the font-size, positioning, color, etc. but just can't get it right.  It would be nice if there were some sort of FFPLAY for the browser.

Is there some sort of approach/technique for creating an in-browser preview prior to encoding with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WebVTT](https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/) in your HTML5 video player. [CSS is used for styling](https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#styling).

You can use `ffmpeg` to convert the SRT to VTT:

```
ffmpeg -i input.srt output.vtt
```